# Using the same prefix for multiple custom post types in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the default custom post type for news, with resulting URL:

`myurl.com/news/news-item-title`

Great, this is what I want.  I am also aware that I can create custom post types and use `'with_front' => false` to achieve:

`myurl.com/news/news-item-title` AND `myurl.com/customposttype/customposttype-title`

However, what I want to do is group multiple custom post types under the same parent URL, for example:

`myurl.com/parenturl/customposttype1/customposttype1-title`
`myurl.com/parenturl/customposttype2/customposttype2-title`
`myurl.com/parenturl/customposttype3/customposttype3-title`

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the following code into your themes functions.php file

```
add_action('init','add_rewrite_rules');
function add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'parenturl/customposttype1/customposttype1-([^/]+)?$',
        'index.php?post_type=customposttype1&name=$matches[1]',
        'top'
        );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'parenturl/customposttype2/customposttype2-([^/]+)?$',
        'index.php?post_type=customposttype2&name=$matches[1]',
        'top'
        );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'parenturl/customposttype3/customposttype3-([^/]+)?$',
        'index.php?post_type=customposttype3&name=$matches[1]',
        'top'
        );
}
```

This basically creates custom rewrite rules for you that finds your custom post types and matches the name of your post to a regular expression.

You will also need to [Flush your rewrite rules](https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/) after adding this code.

Comment: Thanks!  This works really well.  The only problem now is that the original URL's (minus the `parenturl` string, still resolve.  Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Do you just want to show a 404 error when myurl.com/customposttype/customposttype-title is displayed?